# Removing a node from rendezvous_hash::RendezvousNodes in Rust

Tags: rust, mutable, borrow-checker, rendezvous-hash

I am trying to remove a node from the RendezvousNodes collection of the rendezvous_hash crate.

The shortened example code I am using is:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use rendezvous_hash::{RendezvousNodes, Node};
use rendezvous_hash::{WeightedNode, Capacity};

fn main() {
    let mut nodes = RendezvousNodes::default();


    let node1 = WeightedNode::new("foo", Capacity::new(70.0).unwrap());
    nodes.insert(node1);
    println!("{}", nodes.len());

    for node in nodes.iter() {
        println!("{}", node.node_id());
    }

    nodes.remove(node1.node_id());
    println!("{}", nodes.len());
}
```

This fails because of value borrowed after move.

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `node1`
  --> src/main.rs:17:18
   |
9  |     let node1 = WeightedNode::new("foo", Capacity::new(70.0).unwrap());
   |         ----- move occurs because `node1` has type `WeightedNode<&str>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
10 |     nodes.insert(node1);
   |                  ----- value moved here
...
17 |     nodes.remove(node1.node_id());
   |                  ^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

Passing in a reference for node works:

```
...
    nodes.insert(&node1);
...
```

However, now I have to keep track of the node value myself which I do not want, and it likely creates later problems with scope and lifetime.
It should be sufficient to have the `nodes` collection keeping track of its nodes.

Is there a way to remove the node though it is owned by nodes now, or is this a problem of the crate?

Comment: "now I have to keep track of the node value myself "

Well if you wouldn't keep track of it, then how were you ever planning to remove the node again at some later stage?

Comment: @Lagerbaer I can always query the node_id by iterating over the nodes. I admit bad wording, I need to keep track of the node_id, but not of the object itself.

Comment: Maybe your minimal example is too minimal then? Can you demonstrate the case where you insert a node first, and then _later_, _somewhere else_ want to remove it?

Comment: The crate is fine, but you need to understand how Rust's ownership and borrowing rules work.  https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html

Comment: Yes, just found it, by reading the source for the 10th time. I just need to pass a reference to the node_id like this `nodes.remove(&"foo");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the source for the `remove` method:

```
/// Removes the specified node from the candidates.
    ///
    /// If the node does not exist, this method will return `None`.
    pub fn remove<M>(&mut self, node_id: &M) -> Option<N>
    where
        N::NodeId: Borrow<M>,
        M: PartialEq,
    {
        if let Some(i) = self
            .nodes
            .iter()
            .position(|n| n.node_id().borrow() == node_id)
        {
            Some(self.nodes.swap_remove(i))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
```

from

[docs.rs](https://docs.rs/rendezvous_hash/0.3.0/src/rendezvous_hash/lib.rs.html#1-322)

it gets clear that passing a reference to the node_id does it.

`nodes.remove(&"foo");`

EDIT:

And if I had read the docs more thoroughly, I would probably have spotted:

```
// Update the node set.
// (The relative order between existing nodes are preserved)
nodes.remove(&"baz");
```